# How to add a category column in SQL and resize the records by creating views in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I need to create SQL Views which will convert the current table into the desired format mentioned below

I have introduce a new category column and reshape the columns accordingly.

Curent table layout:

```
     Date  | A flows| B flows | C flows | A yield | B Yield | C Yield | A Spread |  B Spread |  C Spread
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1/1/17 |10      | 20      |30       |   5     |10       |15       | 1        |  2        |3
```

Desired View layout:

```
         Date   Category    flows   yield   Spread
         1/1/17     A       10       5       1
         1/1/17     B       20       10      2
         1/1/17     C       30       15      3
```

Can anyone help create a SQL View which will categorize existing columns under 3 categories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `cross apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (date, 'A', A_Flows, A_yield, A_spread),
             (date, 'B', B_Flows, B_yield, B_spread),
             (date, 'C', C_Flows, C_yield, C_spread)
      ) v(date, category, flows, yield, spread);
```

You can put `create view as` before the query to create a view.

Comment: I believe the intended literals in the second and third row value expressions are `'B; and 'C'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `UNION`. Select each category separately and then join the 3 categories together:

```
SELECT Date, 'A' AS Category, A_flows AS flows, A_yield AS yield, A_spread AS spread FROM your_table
UNION
SELECT Date, 'B' AS Category, B_flows AS flows, B_yield AS yield, B_spread AS spread FROM your_table
UNION
SELECT Date, 'C' AS Category, C_flows AS flows, C_yield AS yield, C_spread AS spread FROM your_table
```